# Что за переменная $q ?

Tags: база-данных, php

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = **'".$q."'**";
```

и что означают точки до и перед `$q`?

Comment: кто плюсует такие вопросы? Тут вопроса как такового нет. просто недочитанный материал по php.

Answer (score 6):

[Оператор конкатенации](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.string.php). Если вы с ней еще не знакомы, значит вам стоит вернуться назад в своём изучении - к работе с базами данных вы еще не готовы.

К слову, заменить можно на одну из этих записей:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = '$q'";   // обратите внимание, что кавычки двойные
$sql="SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = '{$q}'"; // в одинарных такое не прокатит
```

Но, боюсь, это вас запутает еще сильнее.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. С конкатенацией знаком. Непонятно, почему там эта переменная,а не таблица, например. Куда идет обращение в дб?

Comment: Запрос идёт к таблице ``user``, делается выборка записей, ``id`` которых равно значению переменной ``$q``